# Library/script to do a sliding effect on a website

Tags: web-development, gui, graphic-design

On my website I want to implement a sliding effect: when you scroll down and reach a new section, an image comes from the right and slides to its final place.

[Example of a site with the effect I am looking for (towards the middle)](http://www.adhamdannaway.com/featured)

Comment: What effect are you talking about? The slider effect? Please edit your question talking about the effect your looking for

Comment: Sorry I'll edit this as soon as possible , and yes is about the slide effect on the webpage